# printf prints commas to file

Tags: bash, printf, gitlab-ci, double-quotes

I'm having an environment variable that get's printed to a file which is then read by my program. When the variable gets written to the file it looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN
,RSA
,PRIVATE
,KEY-----
,MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAtxPgpPqD1cZdoTeOMvOnqp0NkkCqcMsn8V4j9KrFWpPxiweu
,H1r69S2ssmuqtleLVKk2kwgTn6x+AvcqgTBLsjnfpPmD2mBKvTqCvaBT2VXdxGiA
,dlp  etc....
```

When it should look like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAtxPgpPqD1cZdoTeOMvOnqp0NkkCqcMsn8V4j9KrFWpPxiweu
H1r69S2ssmuqtleLVKk2kwgTn6x+AvcqgTBLsjnfpPmD2mBKvTqCvaBT2VXdxGiA
dlpJMJAvCwBsDnDRilSRoNja4DpF26bHSQePwZF1/4OqnF6GtvGcPPPENiJkjxr/ etc...
```

My script command looks like this:

```
- printf '%s\n', $PRIVATE_KEY > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/private.pem
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect the `,` in `'%s\n',` to do, if not to tell printf to write a comma after each newline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf '%s\n' "$PRIVATE_KEY" > "$CI_PROJECT_DIR"/private.pem
```

Quote `"$PRIVATE_KEY"` to prevent it from being split into separate words. As a rule of thumb, always quote variable expansions to prevent accidental mangling of their values. It's a good habit to get into.

Also, remove the trailing comma from `'%s\n',`. Shell script arguments are not comma-separated.